# L5 random TokenMismatchExceptions

Tags: php, laravel, csrf, laravel-5

I'm getting random TokenMismatchExceptions in Laravel 5. Using the following code in the `tokensMatch()` function I've been trying to debug this weird issue:

```
Log::debug($request->session()->token(). ', ' . $token);
```

The output is as follows:

```
[2015-03-21 17:04:22] local.DEBUG: XJhAXXQumM0JLX9tFcQn1tQZMI1FtglDFuhi8abT, XJhAXXQumM0JLX9tFcQn1tQZMI1FtglDFuhi8abT  
[2015-03-21 17:04:34] local.DEBUG: XJhAXXQumM0JLX9tFcQn1tQZMI1FtglDFuhi8abT, XJhAXXQumM0JLX9tFcQn1tQZMI1FtglDFuhi8abT  
[2015-03-21 17:04:36] local.DEBUG: snE0IERJ1VY0o4qmSMuHb4wH9lhQUf5ZtVObOFnR, XJhAXXQumM0JLX9tFcQn1tQZMI1FtglDFuhi8abT  
[2015-03-21 17:04:36] local.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php:47
Stack trace:
[...]
[2015-03-21 17:07:30] local.DEBUG: XJhAXXQumM0JLX9tFcQn1tQZMI1FtglDFuhi8abT, XJhAXXQumM0JLX9tFcQn1tQZMI1FtglDFuhi8abT
```

As you can see, the first 2 requests succeed, the 3rd one fails and the 4th one succeeds again. I've been using Fiddler and Chrome network tools and I can confirm that the exact same data was sent to the server for all requests.

So it seems the token changes on the server side. The weird thing is that the token in the session file doesn't seem to change, and the wrong token is always a string I haven't seen before, but always gets reverted to the original string somehow.

This happens pretty often, so it's really annoying. First I thought it may be something about the database session driver, but I'm using the file driver now and it's still happening.

**Update**

I keep having this problem. I have it on different PC's and different projects using `php artisan serve`. I also have it on different servers and different projects (nginx 1.6.2, PHP 5.6.7).

[I'm not the only one with this problem](http://laravel.io/forum/01-30-2015-laravel5-tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken).

It's pretty hard to debug as it happens randomly, sometimes it doesn't show up for some time and then suddenly it happens many times in a row, or just once. By simply resubmitting the POST request it sometimes works again, or sometimes results in another exception.

Only thing I added to `composer.json` in all projects is `"illuminate/html": "5.*"`. All composer packages are up-to-date.

I'll update this question as soon as I've more info regarding this really weird problem.

**Another update**

I created a new L5 project, and added some minimal code to reproduce this error. The changes I made can be seen [here](https://github.com/Naxiz/L5-CSRF-TestCase/commit/74d8222551cd0383c5887b108967b634c7af3b15) (along with the complete test project). I'll try some debugging with this project now.

Comment: Have you made any modifications to your Laravel session config?

Comment: Yes, I've changed the driver to database but I've reverted it to file because I thought it may have caused the problem, but the problem still persists.

Comment: What's your setup? i.e. Apache/Nginx, PHP version etc. Also, can you let me know whether the token stored within the cookie changes? You can do this via developer tools > resources > Cookies

Comment: Also, are you using any AJAX within your app?

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.6.5 and the built-in web server. I'm not using any AJAX in my app. The token doesn't seem to change, but I'll watch it a bit more closely tomorrow.

Comment: Well, I had it a few times again but not as much as I did so it's pretty hard to debug the issue now. It also happened using nginx on production once, so I guess it's really an issue in Laravel. Maybe the latest update fixed this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known issue with Laravel 5 for *some* people.

There is an open Github issue ticket on this topic here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8172

The cause is not yet known, and it has been going on for a while. There are a lot of smart people looking into it - but the apparent randomness of the issue is making it difficult to debug.

I suggest you contribute your information to that ticket and keep an eye there for further information.

Comment: They closed the issue without solving it.

Comment: Update: Here is an issue and possible solution for [L5.2](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13064)