# Random TokenMismatchException on Chrome

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

There's a strange error occurring on my laravel application and I'm completely lost at how to fix it

When I'm submitting a form, it sometimes likes to randomly show the TokenMismatchException after the form has been submitted. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. It's completely random ... and it only happens on chrome. Any other browser works perfectly fine.

After experimenting, I realized that it works perfectly fine when I don't select "remember me" during login. By doing this, it doesn't create the *remember_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d* cookie.

Is there a way that this remember_web cookie is somehow interfering with csrf token?

I'm completely stumped. I'm also confused why this happens only on chrome and not Firefox.

Comment: I am also getting this bug in one of my laravel projects and the closed answer for this problem is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29184992/l5-random-tokenmismatchexceptions?rq=1 . I recommend you to upgrade to laravel 5.5 and check again. If you are using laravel 5.4, the upgrade will not break anything and only take hardly 10 min max.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and even worst, the application didn't start at all! after some search i reach to that point maybe it is from browser coockie(I'm not sure) so I delete the coockie and I deleted my user from the database and registered him again. now it's working fine.

Comment: It seems that deleting the user and creating it again has fixed the error. Strange ...  Hopefully it stays fixed!